# Why does sockjs (in meteor) make the same request over and over?

Tags: meteor, sockjs

I've been seeing intermittent downtime with my application in production. I have 3 app instances behind Amazon ALB (load balancer) and NGINX. Occasionally, I will see one app server go to 100% and become unresponsive. Eventually, the other boxes unresponsive and stay unresponsive for about 3 hours. Restarting the docker containers the app is running in or restarting the EC2 machines doesn't seem to help. This makes me think there is something happening at the network level the impacts all instances. At this point I've ruled out large data sets, long running operations, scary cron jobs etc and have noticed a pattern of a barrage of /sockjs/ requests that I can't explain.

The one thing I do see is a A LOT of requests in my nginx logs to /sockjs/. Usually I only see one request like this per creation of a new browser/client session. Here is an example of the sockjs requests we've been getting for the past 5 hours continuously. I've truncated it but the pattern repeats. I've also taken a look at this user session (we use FullStory) and have verified that user isn't up to much during this time.

Does anyone know:
- What it means when I see these logs over and over again?
- What causes them to repeat so many times in a single minute?
- How can I reproduce this situation? (it does not seem to be a malicious attempt by a user)
- Is this normal?

For brevity here is the part that repeats: `/sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0`

Here's a rundown to show how frequently it happens.

```
Aug 17 08:00:05 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:05 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:05 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:05 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:06 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:06 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:07 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:07 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:08 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:08 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 298 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:15 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:15 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 

Aug 17 07:50:03  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:03 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:04  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:04 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:04  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:04 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:07  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:07  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 11187 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:09  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:09 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 1651 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:10  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:10 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:10  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:10 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 114 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:12  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:12 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:12  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:12 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:13  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:13 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 1075 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:15  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:15 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:15  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:15 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:16  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:16 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:17  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:17 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:17  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:17 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:18  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:18 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 298 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:22  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:22 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:22  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:22 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:22  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:22 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:23  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:23 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:23  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:23 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:23  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:23 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 53 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:23  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:23 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:23  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:23 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 376 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:24  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:24 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:24  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:24 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:24  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:24 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 197 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:35  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:35 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:35  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:35 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:36  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:36 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:37  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:37 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:37  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:37 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:38  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:38 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 298 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:45  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:45 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:45  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:45 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:46  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:46 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:47  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:47 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:47  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:47 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:48  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:48 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 298 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:54  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:54 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:54  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:54 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:55  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:55 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:56  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:56 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:56  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:56 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:50:57  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.5.244 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:50:57 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 415 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:51:00  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:51:00 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 07:51:00  nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:14:51:00 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
.
.
.
Aug 17 08:00:05 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:05 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:05 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:05 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:06 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:06 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:07 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:07 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:07 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:08 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:08 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr HTTP/1.1" 200 298 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" 
Aug 17 08:00:15 nginx.1    | sunsama.com 172.31.32.175 - - [17/Aug/2017:15:00:15 +0000] "POST /sockjs/372/_7p3spix/xhr_send HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://sunsama.com/group/appeagle?mfids=XmBSmwTwSKyNaWCzd&cv=week" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on, perhaps there are some problems, and it is constantly retrying? Maybe sockets access is firewalled out?